# {segment_category_ids_piped} only returning one cat id

Tags: low-seg2cat

EE3

first_segment = /cycling

I've added the following to a template:

```
{segment_category_ids_piped}
```

But it only returns a single category, even though 'cycling' is present in 2 category groups, and twice in one group!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple categories with the same URL title, then [this caveat applies](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-seg2cat/docs#caveats):

> If there are multiple categories with the same url_title, but in different groups, this extension will only return one of those. So best make sure your category url_titles are unique, or you select the relevant Category Groups in the settings so they are.

The `piped` var is meant to be used if there are multiple categories in the URI, so something like `/foo/cat1/cat2` would return `1|2` for those two categories.